# Web components and click events - discrepancy between Chrome and Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, click, web-component

I have a weird behaviour mismatch between firefox (114.0.2) and chrome (114.0.5735.199) as regards to click events and web components.

I have the following setup HTML.
As you can see, I have a TestButton component which is a simple slotted button. On it, I have a click event and in that I:

1. log to console
2. Set the inner button of the component to disabled for 2 seconds.

The difference comes to light when repeatedly clicking the button:

- In chrome: the event handler function is called repeatedly and
  console is logged while disabled property is added/removed.
- In Firefox: the first click invokes the function, the button is
  disabled (for two seconds), no further clicks are possible until enabled again. Clicks
  while the button is disabled are ignored.

I think that the required behaviour is Firefox's but, why doesn't it happen also in Chrome?

Obviously, the click event is on the host element and not on the disabled inner button, so why in Firefox it works fine?
Furthermore, I have noticed that if you remove the slot from the button (i.e., replace it with some text), chrome starts to behave as Firefox.

I would appreciate if someone can explain this to me.
Thanks.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <test-button onclick="buttonClicked(this)">Test Button</test-button>
<script>
    const TestButton = class extends HTMLElement {
        connectedCallback() {
            this.shadow = this.attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });
            const template = document.createElement('template');
            template.innerHTML = "<button><slot></slot></button>";
            this.shadow.appendChild(template.content.cloneNode(true));
        }
    }

    customElements.define("test-button", TestButton);

    function buttonClicked(element) {
        console.log("log", element.tagName);
        const innerButton = element.shadow.querySelector("button");
        innerButton.setAttribute("disabled", true);
        setTimeout(() => {
            innerButton.removeAttribute("disabled");
        }, 2000);
    }
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you use the [<>] button in the SO editor and make it a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click.

Comment: I have added it to the WHATWG issue where Google, Apple and Mozilla engineers discus disabled elements: https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5886#issuecomment-1615942026

Comment: A JSFiddle (which can be gone next week) is not an SO Snippet you add with the **[<>] button**. See my link to the WHATWG Issue list above, Google engineers have a fix ready.

Comment: Hey @Danny'365CSI'Engelman, thank you for your attention. Wasn't aware of adding running snippets directly in SO. Anyways, I hope the fix will roll out soon.